# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an error when I try to run my program:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a  datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Is there anything wrong with my select statement?

```
  int month=0;

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    { month = 1; }
    else if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    { month = 2; }
    else if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    { month = 3; }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] Where thDate > dateadd(month, -" + month + ", GETDATE())", myConnection);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    myConnection.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "[Transaction]");
    myConnection.Close();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["vs_Transaction"] = (DataTable)ds.Tables["Transaction"];
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Transaction"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

The below is my database table for thDate

[image]

[image]

Comment: is in the title, I guess

Comment: There was a comment that says "And what is the error?".. but I think that was deleted :P

Comment: Do you have any idea what's the problem with my coding that causes the erorr ?

Comment: where do you get the error ? What line ? give us a little more info

Comment: also, your data is varchar type ? that's what is looks like..

Comment: yah my data is varchar. they said The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. At da.Fill(ds, "[Transaction]");

Comment: try to use `Convert(datetime,  thDate,120)` in your select, and in the where. If this work for you, I will post it as an answer

Comment: hi, you mean which part of the select? at there where clause ?

Comment: `SELECT Convert(datetime, thDate,120), thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] Where Convert(datetime, thDate,120)> dateadd(month, -" + month + ", GETDATE())", myConnection);`

Comment: hi, i've tried and it's the same error .

Comment: sorry, use `Convert(datetime, thDate,103)`. Replace the 120 with 103, this should work !! I've tried and work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're storing the data as `Varchar`, and filling the `datatable`, that probably will expect a `Datetime`. You should `cast` the values  in the `query` in two places:

- In the `select`, for returning as a `Date`
- In the `Where`, because you're comparing a `Date` against a
  `Varchar`.

So, your `select` clause will be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Convert(datetime, thDate,103) as thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] Where Convert(datetime, thDate,103)> dateadd(month, -" + month + ", GETDATE())", myConnection);
```

Comment: there's no more error. However the date in the gridview was not selected based on the radio button selection . Do you have any idea why?

Comment: For example ? What is the date in your Db, and what is the date showed on the GridView?

Comment: I've edited the top. The date in db and gridview should be the same

Comment: Well, are you sure that the Db result that you first show is Ok ? I mean, your Where clause is adding 0, 1 OR 2 to getdate() (which means, actual date), and returning the fields that are bigger than that. Your first output has a value that was incorrect, "9/2/2012 10:23.." Probably was because it was comparising the fields as Varchar (aka strings) and not as dates. I mean, the select is returning other results. If you are SURE that the first result is that you want, remove the "Convert" in the where (put it as before)

Comment: i've changed the date before that, no more "9/2/2012 10:23". Your first result referring to 9/2/2012? Or ? Because i have removed the "Convert" in the where clause. But it says 
     An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: "your first result" yes, refering to 9/2/2012. So, again, what is the date that youre getting on your db, and what is the wrong date in the datagridview? Also, what values you got in your radioButton ? Is correct the values you're selecting ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14556/discussion-between-kyq-and-elvieejo)